# Available 3D libraries in Python; To convert 3D object formats

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d, blender, fbx

Is there any python library (prefer 2x) where I can load a .x3d 3D object and convert it into FBX?
I'm currently using blender to do so; but I'm in search of a library which can run and be installed on conda. 
Basically, just convert X3D to FBX (or .blend without blender :P)
Even an external online service would do. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is off-topic for the following reason: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: If you don't want to install blender you could use meshlab. Do you know that you can script blender to run guiless from the cli on a server. Note that support for both fbx and x3d in blender are python addons so you should be able to merge the import and export into one without sending it to/from a blender mesh in between.

Comment: @sambler Thanks for the reply. Any idea how to merge the import and export services only into a separate module? and remove blender from the picture

Comment: You would have to find the code that reads x3d and instead of creating a new vert/edge/face in blender send it to the fbx exporter. Maybe creating a [mesh class](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) to respond to the used properties/methods as if it was in blender may be easiest and let you not change the x3d/fbx scripts.